# Solr duplicate documents count based on multi-valued field using faceting

Tags: solr, duplicates, faceted-search

I have to find the count of duplicate documents based on the same values in a multi-valued field. Here documents refer to BI reports in my use case. And this multi-valued field is a metadata of the sql table columns that were used to generate a particular BI report. I know that this can be achieved using solr faceting, but I am not sure how to achieve this when the field is multi-valued and has an analysis chain linked to it (like tokenization, lowercasing etc).

Can someone please help?

Comment: So is the duplication based on the tokenized and processed form of the field, or the raw, stored text in the field?

Comment: the multi-valued field is a comma separated column names from which the BI report was created and those values should be the same (raw form) when we consider exact duplicates.

Comment: @MatsLindh I would like to update you about the current progress so far, regarding the duplicates count. I have enabled multi-value feature for the string field and now solr is faceting on each string value of the multi-value list, which is taking a lot of time and also it isn't what I desired. I wanted to have counts of duplicates based on multi-valued field (the whole list of strings being the same in duplicate documents). Can you please help?

Comment: Index a separate field with all the values concatenated together, either by joining them with `|` or a another separator in your code. You can also [use a ConcatFieldUpdateProcessor to do this in an update processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) for each document submitted if necessary.